# Div container overflow

Tags: css, overflow

I have a div that seems to not be wrapping its inner content

http://c5.dealercontrol.net/inventory/p1

the div id="container" has a black bg and should be wrapping the inner content how can I get it to show the style around all the inner content...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in a "clear" div or property in your html/css.  The code you need is below and i have typed  quick example as to where to place it.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

You would place this tag inside your container div, but after all of the inner contents.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

This may be unrelated, but it seems that `<div id="sort-results">` is missing its closing tag.